# sql.close() Is it still necessary if object = sql.connect and object destroyed at the end? (Node.js Express)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have a function which returns an object that is essentially `sql.connect(<constring>)`. I’m using that function to create a new object (new connection) every time that I need  (for example  `const newPool = await startPool()`

---

My questions is this: 
I’m not using `sql.close` because I assumed that the newPool object is destroyed when the function in which is used is finished. Is this right?

I'm using this to define the connection:

```
    let newPool = null; 

    async function startDatabase() {
        try {
            newPool =await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            errorMsg ='database connection error';
        }
    }

    async function startPool(){
        if(!newPool) await startDatabase(); 
        return newPool;
    }

    module.exports = {
        startPool,
        startDatabase,
    }
```

.. and this is an example where I use it

```
const newPool = await startPool();
const result = await newPool.request()
                .input('email',sql.NVarChar(100),email)
                .query('select SID, active, blockedTemp,hps,slt, SERFid, fName, lName from usr where [email] = @email')
```